# Why can't a method be defined both for a struct and its pointer?

Tags: go

Given the setup in  the [54th slide](http://tour.golang.org/#54) of the golang tour:

```
type Abser interface {
    Abs() float64
}

type Vertex struct {
    X, Y float64
}

func (v *Vertex) Abs() float64 {
    return math.Sqrt(v.X*v.X + v.Y*v.Y)
}
```

Why can't a method also be defined for the struct as well as the pointer to the struct? That is:

```
func (v Vertex) Abs() float64 {
    return math.Sqrt(v.X*v.X + v.Y*v.Y)
}
```

Defining this gives the following error:

```
prog.go:41: method redeclared: Vertex.Abs
    method(*Vertex) func() float64
    method(Vertex) func() float64
```

Comment: [See also](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13303254/720999)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It can. Just define it on the struct and not the pointer. It will resolve both ways

[Method Sets](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets)

> The method set of the corresponding pointer type *T is the set of all
>   methods with receiver *T or T (that is, it also contains the method
>   set of T)

Try live: http://play.golang.org/p/PsNUerVyqp

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
    )

type Abser interface {
    Abs() float64
}

type Vertex struct {
    X, Y float64
}

func (v Vertex) Abs() float64 {
    return math.Sqrt(v.X*v.X + v.Y*v.Y)
}

func main() {
    v := Vertex{5, 10}
    v_ptr := &v
    fmt.Println(v.Abs())
    fmt.Println(v_ptr.Abs())
}
```

*Update:* As per comments I have created an extra example that actually makes use of the `Abser` interface to illustrate that both the value and the pointer satisfy the interface.

https://play.golang.org/p/Mls0d7_l4_t

Comment: The `type Abser interface` is unused.

Comment: @Tom L are you saying your IDE is complaining that your interface is unused? It may not see anything within the same library implementing the interface. What is your actual point or problem?

Comment: Your excellent Go Playground example (that understandably mirrors the question) can also “resolve both ways” without the `type Abser interface`.

Answer (score 4):

While considering for example:

```
type T U

func (t *T) M() int { return 1 }

var t T
```

...we can now invoke `M()` on `t` by writing `t.M()` as the language permits to call a method with a pointer receiver even on its underlying (non pointer) typed instances, i.e. it becomes equivalent to `(&t).M()`.

If it will be permitted to now additionaly define:

```
func (t T) M() int { return 2 }
```

...then there's no way to tell what is now `t.M()` supposed to return.