# Golang pointers

Tags: pointers, go

I am currently learning to program with Go language.
I am having some difficulties understanding Go pointers (and my C/C++ is far away now...).
In the Tour of Go #52 (http://tour.golang.org/#52) for example, I read:

```
type Vertex struct {
    X, Y float64
}

func (v *Vertex) Abs() float64 {
    return math.Sqrt(v.X*v.X + v.Y*v.Y)
}

func main() {
    v := &Vertex{3, 4}
    fmt.Println(v.Abs())
}
```

But if instead of

```
func (v *Vertex) Abs() float64 {
[...]
v := &Vertex{3, 4}
```

I wrote:

```
func (v Vertex) Abs() float64 {
[...]
v := Vertex{3, 4}
```

Or even:

```
func (v Vertex) Abs() float64 {
[...]
v := &Vertex{3, 4}
```

and vice-versa:

```
func (v *Vertex) Abs() float64 {
[...]
v := Vertex{3, 4}
```

I got the exact same result. Is there a difference (memory-wise, etc)?

Comment: Hello and Welcome to Programmers. Direct implementation questions such as these are off-topic here but on topic on Stack Overflow. I will initiate a migrate. Have a pleasant day.

Comment: Try mutating the `v` in all the methods, and then `fmt.Println()` the original after the call, and you'll see the difference. With the `(v Vertex)` versions, you're getting a copy of the original. If it was called on a pointer, it's just dereferenced for you automatically.

Comment: See also: [Method receivers ambiguity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14926860/method-receivers-ambiguity)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There are two different rules of the Go language used by your examples:

1. It is possible to derive a method with a pointer receiver from a method with a value receiver. Thus `func (v Vertex) Abs() float64` will automatically generate an additional method implementation:

   ```
   func (v Vertex) Abs() float64 { return math.Sqrt(v.X*v.X+v.Y*v.Y) }
   func (v *Vertex) Abs() float64 { return Vertex.Abs(*v) }  // GENERATED METHOD
   ```

   The compiler will automatically find the generated method:

   ```
   v := &Vertex{3, 4}
   v.Abs()  // calls the generated method
   ```
2. Go can automatically take the address of a variable. In the following example:

   ```
   func (v *Vertex) Abs() float64 { return math.Sqrt(v.X*v.X+v.Y*v.Y) }
   func main() {
       v := Vertex{3, 4}
       v.Abs()
   }
   ```

   the expression `v.Abs()` is equivalent to the following code:

   ```
   vp := &v
   vp.Abs()
   ```

Comment: Does doing *v generates a copy of v in memory (Vertex struct)? If No then do the change in v itself during execution of func (v Vertex) Abs() reflect outside?

Comment: A new copy of struct Vertex is created before entering `func (v Vertex) Abs()`.

Comment: @Atom Isn't it more correct to write in the first case, when the struct Vertex is copied before entering `func (v Vertex) Abs()`: `func (v *Vertex) Abs() float64 { return (*v).Abs() }  // GENERATED METHOD`? I'm having problems understanding Vertex.Abs(*v) ...

Comment: `(*v).Abs()` would also be correct and it is equivalent to `Vertex.Abs(*v)`. The two expressions are equivalent, they only have different syntax.

Comment: How do you get the pointer to a member of a struct?  You've got the point to v.  How do you get the pointer to a member of v?

Answer (score 13):

There are differences. For example, the non-pointer receiver form forces the method to work on a copy. This way the method is not able to mutate the instance it was invoked on - it can access only the copy. Which might be ineffective in terms of e.g. time/memory performance/consumption etc.

OTOH, pointer to instances and methods with pointer receivers allow for easy instance sharing (and mutating) where desirable.

More details [here](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_expressions).

Answer (score 2):

The difference is pass-by-referenve vs pass-by-value.

In `func f(v Vertex)` the argument is *copied* into parameter `v`. In `func f(v *Vertex)` a pointer to an existing `Vertex` instance is passed.

When using methods, some of the dereferencing can be done for you, so you can have a method `func (v *Vertex) f()` and call it without taking a pointer first: `v := Vertex{...}; v.f()`. This is just a grain of syntax sugar, AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

There are two main differences in those examples:

```
func (v *Vertex) Abs()....
```

The receiver will be *passed-by-reference* for v and you would be able to call this method only on pointers:

```
v := Vertex{1,3}
v.Abs() // This will result in compile time error
&v.Abs() // But this will work
```

On the other hand

```
func (v Vertex) Abs() ....
```

You can call this method on both pointers and structs. The receiver will be *passed-by-value* even when you call this method on pointers.

```
v := Vertex{1,3}
v.Abs() // This will work, v will be copied.
&v.Abs() // This will also work, v will also be copied.
```

You can declare both `func (v *Vertex)` and `func (v Vertex)`.

Answer (score 0):

As the specification says

> A method call x.m() is valid if the method set of (the type of) x contains m and the argument list can be assigned to the parameter list of m. If x is addressable and &x's method set contains m, x.m() is shorthand for (&x).m():

In your case v.Abs() is shorthand for &v.Abs() if method is addressable.