# Interfaces and Pointers in Golang tour #55 and #57

Tags: go

In these two tutorial examples, why does a method with a pointer receiver satisfy an interface in one case but not the other?

In [example #55](http://tour.golang.org/#55) the class `Vertex` doesn't satisfy the `Abser` interface because method `Abs` is only defined for `*Vertex` and not `Vertex`:

```
type Abser interface {
    Abs() float64
}

type Vertex struct {
    X, Y float64
}

func (v *Vertex) Abs() float64 {
    return math.Sqrt(v.X*v.X + v.Y*v.Y)
}
```

The error message is:

```
prog.go:22: cannot use v (type Vertex) as type Abser in assignment:
    Vertex does not implement Abser (Abs method has pointer receiver)
```

But in [example #57](http://tour.golang.org/#57), the class `MyError` satisfies the `error` interface ok even though `Error()` is defined for `*MyError` and not `MyError`:

```
type error interface {
    Error() string
}

type MyError struct {
    When time.Time
    What string
}

func (e *MyError) Error() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("at %v, %s",
        e.When, e.What)
}
```

From the description in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15098892/4540), it seems like both should work ok, but the tutorial demonstrates the first one failing.  What's the difference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in example57, the error is returned as such:

```
return &MyError{
    time.Now(),
    "it didn't work",
}
```

this returns a pointer to the MyError struct. And `*MyError` satisfies the interface.

In example55 this is also pointed out:

```
a = &v // a *Vertex implements Abser

// In the following line, v is a Vertex (not *Vertex)
// and does NOT implement Abser.
a = v
```

As it says in the answer you are referring to, the generation occurs when it's the other way around (`*MyStruct` type will have all the methods `MyStruct` has)

Answer (score 3):

In #57 only `*MyError` satisfies the `error`. As you can see, the value returned from `run()` is `*MyError`, not `MyError`:

```
func run() error {
    return &MyError{ // <<< Notice the '&'.
        time.Now(),
        "it didn't work",
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In [#57](http://tour.golang.org/#57) it is returning a pointer to my Error:

```
return &MyError{ //notice the "&", that means return the address / pointer to that struct.
    time.Now(),
    "it didn't work",
}
```