# Golang method receiver

Tags: go, interface

According [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15096329/golang-pointers), golang will generate both `type-receiver method` and `point-receiver method`, which means the code below will work correctly and the value will change unexpectedly.

```
func (test *Test) modify() {
    test.a++
}

func main() {
    test := Test{10}
    fmt.Println(test)
    test.modify()
    fmt.Println(test)
}
```

I think it's acceptable to me. But when this mixes with interface, thing goes wrong.

```
type Modifiable interface {
    modify()
}

type Test struct {
    a int
}

func (test *Test) modify() {
    test.a++
}

func main() {
    test := Test{10}
    fmt.Println(test)
    test.modify()
    fmt.Println(test)

    var a Modifiable

    a = test
}
```

it said:

```
Test does not implement Modifiable (modify method has pointer receiver)
```

Why will this happen ?

And how golang actually handle method call ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you said:

```
func (test *Test) modify() {
    test.a++
}
```

It means the interface `Modifiable` is implemented by the type `*Test` aka the *Pointer to Test*

Where as

```
func (test Test) modify() {
        test.a++
}
```

means that the interface is implemented by the type `Test`

Conclusion is: A type and a pointer to that type are 2 different types.

Comment: But the `test` variable do have a method called `modify` and i can call by `test.modify()`, why it said `Test does not implement Modifiable`?

Comment: Because you implemented the interface on `*Test` and not `Test`. The `modify` method is defined for `*Test` and not for `Test` type. When you are calling `test.modify` the compiler will automatically pass a `*Test` but from interface implementation point of view you need to explicitly use `*Test`

Comment: So the answer in given link is wrong , the method for `Test` is not generated ? What compiler really do is pass the pointer to `pointer-method` instead of calling the non-exist generating method .

Comment: Yes, no method is generated. Check out https://tour.golang.org/methods/6 and https://tour.golang.org/methods/7

Comment: Thanks a lot. @Ankur

Answer (score 1):

if you wanted to use a method that has pointer receiver. It means you have to pass the address value.

here is the example :

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Modifiable interface {
    modify()
}

type Test struct {
    a int
}

func (test *Test) modify() {
    test.a++
}

func main() {
    test := Test{10}
    fmt.Println(test)
    test.modify()
    fmt.Println(test)

    var a Modifiable

    a = &test
    a.modify()
    fmt.Println(a)
}
```

In conclusion an interface will accept the address value whenever you create a pointer receiver in the method.